# VIM global multiple line search and replace maintaining indent

Tags: search, vim, replace, whitespace, indentation

I am trying to perform a multiple line search and replace while retaining the indent, leading space, in the code I am working with.  Below is a text sample which approximates the situation.  The problem I'm having is preserving the white space.  I'm hoping for a non-plugin, plain jane VIM solution via :%s/ ......

VIM 7.2 on Windows 7
autoindent is on
expandtab is on

**Starting with:**

```
  apples,
  banannas,
  cherries,
  plums

  peas,
  green beans,
  corn,
  squash

        apples,
        banannas,
        cherries,
        plums
```

**I would like to add "pears,", without the double quotes and following the "cherries," line in the list.  The desired outcome is:**

```
  apples,
  banannas,
  cherries,
  pears,
  plums

  peas,
  green beans,
  corn,
  squash

        apples,
        banannas,
        cherries,
        pears,
        plums
```

---

Trying   **:%s/cherries,/&\rpears,/g**   yields ...

```
      apples,
      banannas,
      cherries,
pears,
      plums

      peas,
      green beans,
      corn,
      squash

            apples,
            banannas,
            cherries,
pears,
            plums
```

---

Trying   **:%s/cherries,_s.\s*/&pears,\r/g**      yields ...

```
      apples,
      banannas,
      cherries,
      pears,
plums

      peas,
      green beans,
      corn,
      squash

            apples,
            banannas,
            cherries,
            pears,
plums
```

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take advantage of `:g` and auto-indentation with normal `o`:

`:g/cherries,/normal opears,`

Answer (score 3):

Try to extract the whitespace just before the word and insert it in the replacement part (`\1`).

**NOTE** that I use `\v` at the beginning but it does not match anything, it is to make the regular expression very magic and avoid to escape many characters, like parentheses.

```
:%s/\v(\s*)cherries,/&\r\1pears,/g
```

It yields:

```
  apples,
  banannas,
  cherries,
  pears,
  plums

  peas, 
  green beans,
  corn,
  squash

        apples,
        banannas,
        cherries,
        pears,
        plums
```